# urban airship , device token is null

Tags: iphone, ios, device, token, urbanairship.com

I have implemented push notification using urban airship (development) in iPhone.

it works fine. I want to test in an new device . I installed the same project in new device from new mac PC I also added the certificate in keychain and run , but the log shows device token is null and no new device token in urban dashboard .

what the reason of null device token ? is there something missing? Shall I do something with .p12 file ?

I have this in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
// Get the results out to open or close notification
    bool storedresult =  [defaults boolForKey:airShipKey];

    if(storedresult){
        [UAPush shared].pushEnabled=YES;
    }else{
        [UAPush shared].pushEnabled=NO;
    }


    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    //Create Airship options directory and add the required UIApplication launchOptions
    NSMutableDictionary *takeOffOptions = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [takeOffOptions setValue:launchOptions forKey:UAirshipTakeOffOptionsLaunchOptionsKey];

    // Call takeOff (which creates the UAirship singleton), passing in the launch options so the
    // library can properly record when the app i launched from a push notification. This call is
    // required.
    //
    // Populate AirshipConfig.plist with your app's info from https://go.urbanairship.com
    [UAirship takeOff:takeOffOptions];

    // Set the icon badge to zero on startup (optional)
    [[UAPush shared] resetBadge];



    [[UAPush shared]
     registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                         UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
                                         UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

    // Handle any incoming incoming push notifications.
    // This will invoke `handleBackgroundNotification` on your UAPushNotificationDelegate.
    [[UAPush shared] handleNotification:[launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]
                       applicationState:application.applicationState];
```

and here is the didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {


    UA_LINFO(@"APNS device token: %@", deviceToken);
    // Updates the device token and registers the token with UA.
    [[UAPush shared] registerDeviceToken:deviceToken];

}
```

I hope you can Help me

Answer (score 0):

Where do you see the `null` value? In the Urban Airship dashboard, or in the method

`- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)newDeviceToken`

Comment: In the Xcode log...  from this method.. it gives me as json with list of properties and one of them device token= ""

Comment: it's too long ..I posted below